# Toolbar v7 not working on android 4 and older

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar

Am using support library v7 for Toolbar the app working fine on my android 5.1 but when I try to install the app on older visions it say "unfortunately app name has stop". Am using AIDE on my Android 5.1.

Comment: Add some code..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the Toolbar from [support library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) instead of the [native one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) included in Marshmallow. You must replace in your code:

**XML**

Replace

```
<Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

by

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

**JAVA**

Change

```
import android.widget.Toolbar;
```

by

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```